# Cheap form of whole-body HIIT

Tags: exercise-equipment, home-exercise, hiit

I am planning to do HIIT and want to buy one (cheap, under $100) piece of equipment for the whole body.

I cannot sprint because I live in a busy city with few open spaces, however I would be fine with equipment like a suspension trainer or skipping rope.

I'm not a beginner, and wouldn't mind high impact exercises.

Please do not recommend bodyweight exercises — they are just not for me (I've tried), and not what this question is about.

If your piece of equipment has any other benefits (eg. portable, scalable), please put that in your answer as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For absolute cheap, I would recommend finding an outdoor fitness trail that has the exercise stations. Usually fairly well planned out with a variety of exercises and activities to hit most of the muscle groups, and if you maintain a high level of speed and exertion, can give you an excellent HIIT style workout.

For an actual piece of equipment, if you are very lucky and persistent, you may be able to find a bench and a small set of dumbbells for under $100. That's just not enough money, however, for a decent (by that I mean won't collapse under you) piece of equipment. I know you said no bodyweight exercises, but for $100, you just aren't going to really find anything worthwhile that is safe. Exercise equipment, even used, is $$.

If you could up your budget, I would look at something like the [TRX Suspension Training](https://www.trxtraining.com/products/trx-full-body-workout-bundle) systems. You can find them anywhere from the MSRP of mid $200's, or lower on Amazon or similar. They are fairly versatile, and when not being used, hang on the wall, so very minimal space.

Answer (score 0):

You could do Farmer's Walks. All you really need is two dumbbells or kettlebells. You could also do Waiter's Walks or swings. These all can be done in a tabata fashion or slightly longer intervals.